# how to use significance in a sentence

Tags: grammar, american-english

I just want to know if the following sentence is correct:

" The **significance** of physics can be found **in** our daily life "

Is "**in**" the appropriate preposition here???

Thank you...

Comment: It's grammatically correct, though rather an odd sentence.

Comment: Thank you, can I write it in this way:  The influence/importance of physics can be found in every aspect of our daily life??

Comment: Yes you can. But your request is not the kind we usually deal with here. It amounts to proof reading, that is checking people's text. If you have a doubt, you need to spell it out. Tell us why you think the use of **significance / in** might not be correct.